# Keep rows separate with write.table R

Tags: r, write.table

I'm trying to produce some files that have slightly unusual field seperators.

```
require(data.table)

dset <- data.table(MPAN = c(rep("AAAA",1000),rep("BBBB",1000),rep("CCCC",1000)),
                   INT01 = runif(3000,0,1), INT02 = runif(3000,0,1), INT03 = runif(3000,0,1))

write.table(dset,"C:/testing_write_table.csv",
            sep = "|",row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, na = "", quote = FALSE, eol = "")
```

I'm findiong however that the rows are not being kept seperate in the output file, e.g.

AAAA|0.238683722680435|0.782154920976609|0.0570344978477806AAAA|0.9250325632......

Would you know how to ensure the text file retains distinct rows?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a UNIX - Windows encoding issue.  So something of a red herring, but perhaps worth recording in case anyone else has this at first perplexing issue.

It turns out that Windows notepad sometimes struggles to render files generated in UNIX properly, a quick test to see if this is the issue is to open in Windows WordPad instead and you may find that it will render properly.

Comment: It works finw with eol = '\n' or with eol undefined.  Turns out I was actually making the situation worse.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks. I managed to replicate your error message when I had `eol=''` but I 'm working on Windows. Maybe it's fine on UNIX. Anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `eol` argument. The end of line argument needs to be a break line:

This worked for me:

```
require(data.table)

dset <- data.table(MPAN = c(rep("AAAA",1000),rep("BBBB",1000),rep("CCCC",1000)),
                   INT01 = runif(3000,0,1), INT02 = runif(3000,0,1), INT03 = runif(3000,0,1))

write.table(dset,"C:/testing_write_table.csv",  #save as .txt if you want to open it with notepad as well as excel
            sep = "|",row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, na = "", quote = FALSE, eol = "\n")
```

Using the break line symbol '\n' as the end of line argument creates separate lines for me.

Comment: No luck for me I'm afraid, Excel can read it in the appropriate as seperate lines as does a copy and paste, but if you look at the txt file raw, it's still printing as a continuous row.  It's a bit strange.  Is it just me experiencing this?

Comment: yeah! it depends on what you want to use to open it. If you just want to open it with excel then save it as '"C:/testing_write_table.csv". If you want both notepad and excel to open it then save it as "C:/testing_write_table.txt". saving it as txt will open it correctly.

Comment: I added a comment on the answer to also mention this.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately... I'm wondering if it could be an issue with encoding (the file is generated from a UNIX instance of R) and opened in Windows.  I'll see what the admins have to say, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: no worries. The above worked for me. Might be some other issue.